# Conditions for unique uniform stationary distribution

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, markov-chains

Is it true that an $\color{blue} {irreducible\; aperiodic \;time-homogeneous}$ Markov chain with finite state space has unique $\color{red} {uniform}$ stationary distribution ? If not , are there any general conditions for  it ?

I only know that such Markov chain has unique stationary distribution by Theorem 1.8.3 of Norris Markov Chain . But I'm not sure about unique  $\color{red} {uniform}$ stationary distribution , I could only see that with finite state space the unique uniform stationary distribution  $\pi = \frac{1}{n} (1,...,1)_{1\times n} , \; n\in \mathbb{Z}^+ <\infty$ .

Comment: Try with two states and transition matrix $\begin{pmatrix} \frac12 &\frac12 \\ 1 &0 \end{pmatrix}$.  Note that the rows each add up to $1$ but the columns do not.  Can a stationary distribution be uniform for such a matrix?

Comment: @Henry no , let your matrix be P , the basis of the left kernel  of $(I-P)$ is $(1,.5)^T$ . So my statement is false